# Bootstrap v4 Responsive Tables Right Margin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with a responsive table in Bootstrap v4. When the table resizes it gives zero margin to the right side of the table. I've tried fixing this by adding a CSS media query with `margin-right: 1em;`. When that didn't work I did some reading online and saw that adding `display: table;` to the media query might work, it didn't though. Anyone know how to either add margin to the right side of the responsive table or remove margin from the left side of the responsive table?

Answer (score 0):

### Bootstrap v4

In order to properly use margin or spacing in bootstrap v4:

```
.mr-1 {
  margin-right: ($spacer-x * .25) !important;
}
```

OR

```
.pr-2 {
  padding-right: ($spacer-x * .5) !important;
}
```

For better explanation read the official bootstrap [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/).